# MySQL tools which ease creation of SQL JOIN statements?

Tags: sql, mysql

Does anyone know tools which look at a MySQL database, show you all the tables graphically and allow you to create complicated JOIN statements via drag-and-drop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you buy anything, see if the free, official [MySQL's GUI tools](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/) (specifically the **MySQL Query Browser**) will work for you.

Personally, I'm fairly comfortable interacting with MySQL's command line interface and haven't used their GUI tools very much, but I just downloaded Query Browser and it seems like it does exactly what you're looking for.

Also, check out ["Building Queries Visually in MySQL Query Browser"](http://www.packtpub.com/article/building-queries-visually-in-mysql-query-browser) for a nice tour of MySQL Query Browser.

Answer (score 2):

As an update, the MySQL Tools collection is no longer supported, and has been replaced by MySQL Workbench. The documentation can be found here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/index.html and you can download it here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Edit: stumbled across this today too, a good beginner tutorial for mysql workbench -> http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/visual-database-creation-with-mysql-workbench/

Answer (score 0):

[EMS SQL Manager for MySQL](http://www.sqlmanager.net/products/mysql/manager) has query constructor. Can't recall about joins, but they should be supported.